# how to show multi series tooltip at a time in asp.net without using JS

Tags: c#

How can I use compare option using C#

```
for (int k = 1; k < dt.Columns.Count; k++)
{
    object[] objects = new object[numOfObjects];
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if ((dt.Rows[i][k]).ToString() != string.Empty)
        {
            float value = Convert.ToSingle(dt.Rows[i][k]);
            objects[i] = (object)value;
        }
    }
    series.Add(new Serie { data = objects, name = input[k-1] });
    hcColumnChart.DataSource = series;
    hcColumnChart.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Your question is week, it's not clear what you want to know. But I think you are looking for .equals method, which you can implement in classes or use or primitive types.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are loking for multiple series on same chart ?

```
for (int k = 1; k < dt.Columns.Count; k++)
 {
  Series series = new Series();
  for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
   {
     if ((dt.Rows[i][k]).ToString() != string.Empty)
      {
        float value = Convert.ToSingle(dt.Rows[i][k]);
        series.Points.AddXY("enter_your_seriesname", value);
      }
   }
  hcColumnChart.Series.Add(series);
  hcColumnChart.DataBind();
}
```

[source](http://www.dotnetfox.com/articles/create-multi-column-or-multi-series-bar-chart-from-database-in-Asp-Net-1063.aspx)